# R - Merging together two spreadsheets with special conditions

Tags: r, csv, merge, conditional-statements, spreadsheet

I am trying to merge together two spreadsheets (CSV files) in R with somewhat complicated conditions.  Each data file contains a list of marine species and categorical ecological assignments (in the form of being assigned a number, 1-6). See pictures for all column headers.

The two files are:

my_data.csv

matt_data.csv

I want to match them by genus name (a column header in both spreadsheets).  If the genus name matches I want to merge the data together.

Special conditions:

1) If the genus name doesn’t match, and it’s in matt_data but not my_data I want the row associated with the genus to be discarded.  my_data contains only currently existing species whereas matt_data contains some extinct species, and I only want currently existing species. If the genus name doesn't match and it's in my_data but not matt_data, I want the row to NOT be deleted.

2) A given genus in matt_data might match multiple rows in my_data, due to matt_data being classified only to the genus level while my_data is classified to the species name.  I want the matt_data to match to all genuses that they share in common.  For example, say homo is a genus in matt_data (being only 1 row) and I have 10 homo genuses in my_data, I want the information in the matt_data row to be nerged to all 10 homo genuses in my_data.

Let me know if any of this doesn’t make sense and I can clarify more.

I previously used a code to merge a different set of spreadsheets (copied below) but it’s not working in this case.  Also I don't believe this code wouldn’t handle my special conditions properly?

```
setwd("C:/Users/TrevorB/Documents/My Documents/Academics/TCBES/Thesis/IUCN WoRMS")


my_list = read.csv("C:/Users/TrevorB/Documents/My Documents/Spreadsheet Ecological Assignment.csv", header=T)
matt_list = read.csv("C:/Users/TrevorB/Documents/My Documents/matt_data.csv", header=T)

my_list$matt_list <- matt_list$category[match(my_list$genus, matt_list$genus)]

write.csv(my_list, file = 'combined.csv')
```

Comment: What your describing is a left join. You can do this in a few different ways, but the easiest is probably using the dplyr package: `left_join(my_list, matt_list, by = "genus")`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: using base R you can use `merge(my_list, matt_list, by = 'genus', all.x = T)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

**base R:**

```
merge(my_list, matt_list, by = 'genus', all.x = T)
```

**plyr:**

```
join(my_list, matt_list, by = 'genus', type = 'left')
```

**dplyr:**

```
left_join(my_list, matt_list, by = 'genus')
```

I personally prefer base R where possible, but the `plyr` one won't rearrange your rows, which is nice.

**Edit:**

You can either remove the `by` argument to match based on all matching column names, or add other columns to join by using `by = c('genus', 'other_col')` etc

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I tried running all three methods and the one issue I was having is all three created a second set of columns for motility, tiering, feeding, and references (such that I had 2 of each of those categories - one from each data set).  Is there a way to merge such that these categories in common also get combined (while still merging by matching genus)?

Comment: you can change the `by` to be a vector to include any number of column names. Or, if you leave it blank it will join by connecting all matching column names between the two dataframes

Comment: also, if this response did answer your question, make sure to tick the 'answered' button to assist future readers

Comment: Thank you for all your help RAB!  When I joined by all the columns I wanted (using both vector and letting R match by leaving blank) none of the matt_data showed up in the combined column. For ex in my data sheet I had 482 tiering rows filled out, in the matt_data sheet 1160 tiering rows are filled out that matched on genus (the 1160 being based on a count of values in the tiering column from matt_data when the datasheets were combined with duplicating columns using just the 'by=genus').  The combined dataset when combining by all matching columns still only has 482 values for tiering.

Comment: I might just manually move the numbers over from the duplicated columns the 'by=genus' function generates, as there are a few entries where I assigned different tiering/motility/feeding values than what's in matt_data.  That's an important quality control step to see where there are disagreements on classification (unless there's a way to highlight if say there's a genus both me and matt filled out, and we have different values for tiering/motility/feeding)

Comment: its hard to know what you are talking about without a reproducible example tbh, so I can't really help any more. Good luck